# Listview in a table or tableview

Tags: android, database, listview, tableview

Is it possible to put a listview with database adapter in a Scrollable table of a table view? To me and others this might sound sound silly but I already have an app coded with multiple scrollable table areas. The screen is split into 4 quadrants with data in each. The data comes from one table in a database. The display always works really great.

This part is for all to hear: I have coded the database data displays into each quadrant with tablerow objects. The problem arises when deleting records. The application has to update all the other table views. This will promote two monsters: 1:)app way too big and 2:) Slow performance. I have a demon crawling up my back that tells me I am programming myself into a corner.
Any hacks, concerns, or start overs are welcome.

Comment: I see this: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-table-layout-example. I don't see any search returns for a listview in a tableview. I smell a rewrite encroaching...

Comment: I believe this might set a better course of action/repair to what I want to do as compared to how the android application is set up for originally. http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/01/android-loading-sqlite-data-tablelayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a open source library whois name is [TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView) that is located in github.

There is also a sample app in this repo to display how it can us your own app.